# How do I create an Appwide method for AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, dialog, alert, android-alertdialog, android-context

I have a few places in my app where I want an alert to pop up and ask the user a question, then get a callback with the selected answer.

Some of the places I want this to happen are in custom non-activity/fragment objects.

I was trying to make a method in my class that derives from Application that would display an AlertDialog but I am always having a context issue and crashing. 
This is a snippet from my application class that has a context = getApplicationContext();

```
public static void showAlert(String title, String message)
{
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
         context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) 
                {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
}
```

What do I need to set my context to so it will not crash? Or is there a better way to do this whole thing?

Thanks,
Alec

Comment: You just have to pass the `Context` to your static method too. Static helper methods in Android normally work this way.

Comment: If you are trying to use an alert dialog in a non-ui portion of your application you are going to have to have some way to access your context.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have it passing in a context, which doesn't solve the problem when it is being called by non-activity classes but works for the other cases.